# How to change r and theta labels in R plotly popup

Tags: r, plotly

I want to create a radar plot using plotly in R. I create numeric values and short names (columns 'question_short' and 'values') for plotting (not to overload the aesthetics of the graphic, because in the real data the labels are much longers), but for the popup in the plot I would like to show full values (columns 'questions' and 'values_label'), is it possible?

Now it shows values from 'question_short' as theta and 'question_short' as r, that are the ones uset for plotting. See image:

[image]

In the popup, Value label: should be 'Low', and the Question: should be 'willing to work'.

This is the example code:

```
plot_df <- data.frame(

  questions = c('level of expertise?', 'willing to work', 'motivation', 'Its friday', 'Chuck Norris'),
  question_short = c('LOE', 'WTW', 'mtvtn', 'frdy', 'ChuNor'),
  values_label = c("Very Low", "Low", "Medium", "High", "Very High"),
  values = c(0:4)
)
 
fig_topic <- plot_ly(
  type = 'scatterpolar',
  fill = 'toself'
)  %>%
  add_trace(
    r = plot_df$values,
    theta = plot_df$question_short,
    name = plot_df$group_id,
    hovertemplate = paste('<i>Value label</i>: %{r}',
                          '<br><b>Question</b>: %{theta}<br>')
  )
 
fig_topic
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your tooltip using the `text=` attribute which allows to use the "longer" versions of your data columns and setting `hoverinfo="text"` to dsiplay only the `text` attribute in the tooltip:

```
library(plotly)

fig_topic <- plot_ly(
  plot_df,
  type = "scatterpolar",
  fill = "toself"
) %>%
  add_trace(
    r = ~values,
    theta = ~question_short,
    #name = ~group_id,
    text = ~paste0(
      "<i>Value label</i>:", values_label,
      "<br><b>Question</b>: ", questions, "<br>"
    ),
    hoverinfo = "text"
  )

fig_topic
```

[image]